# ¿Cuándo debería mover un elemento con margen o una posicion?

Tags: html, css

Desde hace tiempo tengo esta duda para la cual no encuentro respuesta.

Quisiera saber cuando debería usar `position relative` o cuando deberia mover mi elemento con `margin`. Tengo entendido que los 2 ocupan espacio en el flujo de la página, por lo tanto no logro ver la diferencia

Comment: ¿Tienes un caso concreto que quieras ver? `margin` y `position` son dos propiedades diferentes que se usan para cosas distintas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberías usar la posición relativa cuando quieres que los objetos se ajusten en relación a los demás. (que no se superpongan unos con otros).

Y el `margin` es solo una propiedad para agregar un espacio entre un elemento y
los demás.

### Ejemplo:

```css
.caja0{/*top con la posision relativa*/
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: rgb(238, 121, 36);
    
    top:50px;
    position:relative;
}
.caja1{/*top sin posision relativa*/
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: rgb(99, 217, 20);
    
    top:50px;
}
.caja2{/*margin sin posision relativa*/
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: rgb(20, 122, 217);
    
    margin:20px;
    
}
.caja3{/*margin con posision relativa*/
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: rgb(112, 20, 217);
    
    margin:20px;
    position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="caja0">
  caja0
</div>
<div class="caja1">
  caja1
</div>
<div class="caja2">
  caja2
</div>
<div class="caja3">
  caja3
</div>
```

### posición: relativa

> Un elemento con `position: relative;` está posicionado en relación con su posición normal.
>
> Establecer las propiedades superior, derecha, inferior e izquierda de un elemento relativamente posicionado hará que se ajuste lejos de su posición normal. Otro contenido no se ajustará para caber en ningún espacio dejado por el elemento.

---

### Margin

> La propiedad CSS margin establece el margen para los cuatro lados. Es una abreviación para evitar tener que establecer cada lado por separado con las otras propiedades de margen:  margin-top, margin-right, margin-bottom y margin-left.

Ejemplo con la ayuda de

Comment: Listo amigo ya acomode mejor el ejemplo gracias

Comment: Hola ¿Ya te quedo claro o falta una explicación más?